# Embedded images not shown in Google Chrome

Tags: 7, media

I just realized that my embedded images, from an external source, aren't shown up in Google Chrome, but they are working fine in Safari and Firefox.
I cannot even click the link I generated with the tag, as it's not clickable.

Maybe someone has an idea on why this is happening.

```html
<a href="content/httpwwwgooglede#content-top" title="Hier geht's zur Homepage von http://www.google.de"
<img width="404" height="304" border=1" title="" alt="Hier gehts zur Homepage von" http://www.google.de src="http://www.example/external/shots/get.thumbshots.ru/%3Furl=www.google.de%26size=m%26v=1%26lang=en%26"></img></a>
```

This was generated through the Display Suite Module, within a view:

```
<?php $text = ltrim($object->field_link['0']['url'],'http://')?> 
<?php $orig = drupal_lookup_path(source,$object->path); ?>
<a href="<?php print $orig; ?>" class="homepages_klein" title="Hier geht's zur Homepage von <?php print $object->title; ?>">
<img width="202" height="152" title="<?php print $title; ?>" alt="Hier gehts zur Homepage von" <?php print $object->title; ?> src="http://www.kwengo.de/external/shots/get.thumbshots.ru/%3Furl=<?php print $text;?>%26size=m%26v=1%26lang=en%26" /></a>
```

Comment: problem is the invalid html as MPD stated. firefox and safari fix that for you so you can't see the error.

Comment: @Dennis You should use the accept answer feature to mark a question as solved instead of editing the title. This is done by pressing the check mark next to the up/down vote buttons on a question. This indicated that the answer solved your problem

Comment: sorry, i didn't know this. I'll do that in the future. Thanx for your explanation.

Comment: There isn't anything Drupal specific in this question, this is plain HTML. I fail to see how thois question relates to Drupal. Is this HTML generated in a contrib module/theme? If yes, which one?

Comment: Yes it is. The code is generated through the Display Suite module, within a view.

Comment: I attached the code in the 1st post, that you can see, that it's in fact a drupal specific question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is that an exact copy-and-paste?  It isn't valid HTML.  Try

```
<a href="content/httpwwwgooglede#content-top" title="Hier geht's zur Homepage von http://www.google.de">
<img width="404" height="304" border="1" title="" alt="Hier gehts zur Homepage von http://www.google.de" src="http://www.example/external/shots/get.thumbshots.ru/%3Furl=www.google.de%26size=m%26v=1%26lang=en%26" />
</a>
```

I think I fixed everything...

Whenever you have browser differences, run your page through http://validator.w3.org/ and fix the errors first.

Comment: Thanx MPD, you were right. The Problem was the missing">". Thank you very much again.